# How should i deal with a Large database (17mb)?

Tags: android

I have a big database file in my project that is locate in my Assets folder, now i can not devise it to small pieces,
it is another option  to use a  large database file  in the app ??

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Considering that many users have internal space issues with their phones (LG Ally for example). I recommend that you store the data on a web server in a delimited file and create the database on the SD card. If you are worried about the security of your data you could encrypt both the file and the database... though, this may affect performance depending on a few factors.

Although I am not using this for a database in any of my applications, I do use this for downloading application assets so that the apk isn't so large (image sets, sounds, fonts, etc).

Comment: Yes.  The problem is that assets are read only.  It seems that you would have to copy the database from assets into either a plain file or an SqliteDatabase.   Then you're stuck with the original copy in assets taking up space.

I'd be interested in hearing solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

That seems to be an awfully large database for a mobile application.  Is it possible to put the database on a web server and access with through web services-- in other-words-- query the database and have it return an XML dataset that can be easily parsed?

It seems that a web service model would be a better architecture for working with a large database on as mobile device...